# html array index name to variable

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a form such as the below:

```
<form name="basketSelectionForm" action="processBasket.php" method="POST">
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" width="inherit">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img alt="itemNameb" src="images/itemName.jpg" width="70px" height="70px"/></td>
                        <td>Qty. <input value="0" id="itemName" name="basket[itemName]" type="text" style="width:40px;"/>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>

                        <td><img alt="itemName" src="images/itemName.jpg" width="70px" height="70px"/></td>
                        <td>Qty. <input value="0" id="itemName" name="basket[itemName]" type="text" style="width:40px;"/></td>
```

Now when I go to second page to look at the entries of the array, I do this:

```
<?php
    $itemsBasket = array( );
    $itemsBasket = $_POST['basket'];
    echo "<h1>The Items Are...</h1><br>";
    //print_r($itemsBasket);


    foreach ($itemsBasket as $value) 
    {
        if($value > 0){
            echo $value . "<br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

This will print the value at the indexes of the array...but I need to store the name of the index so lets say the item is chocolate and value of 12. I want to extract that index name from array to store it in variable and then assign value to that variable...

Any way I can do that? right now I get only the value while iterating...

Thanks for help and sorry if question isn't clear I will help explain better if so...

UPDATE: this is the unexpected output....

> whitethoab: Array woolthoab: 22 shemag: 22 undershirt: 1 serwalthoab:
>   22 socks: 12

and this is the definition of the element showing as two dimensional array...

```
<td><img alt="White Thoab" src="images/whitethoub.jpg" width="70px" height="70px"/></td>
                        <td>Qty. <input value="0" id="whitethoab" name="basket[whitethoab]" type="text" style="width:40px;"/>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: The whole HTML part is completely irrelevant. This question should just read: "How do I get `foreach` to get the key as well as the value?" To which the answer is, of course, [RTFM](http://php.net/foreach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
<form name="basketSelectionForm" action="processBasket.php" method="POST">
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" width="inherit">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img alt="itemNameb" src="images/itemName.jpg" width="70px" height="70px"/></td>
                        <td>Qty. <input value="12" id="itemName" name="basket[chocolate]" type="text" style="width:40px;"/>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>

                        <td><img alt="itemName" src="images/itemName.jpg" width="70px" height="70px"/></td>
                        <td>Qty. <input value="9" id="itemName" name="basket[onions]" type="text" style="width:40px;"/></td>
```

...and...

```
<?php

    echo "<h1>The Items Are...</h1><br>";

    foreach ($_POST['basket'] as $name => $value) 
    {
        if($value > 0){
            echo $name . ": " . $value . "<br>";
        }
    }

/* Output:
 chocolate: 12
 onions: 9
*/

?>
```

?

Comment: one issue though...the first item printing out of the array is showing as array...while the rest displaying correctly....any idea why? I checked that it is a single dimensional array like shown above ....

Comment: @sys_debug it looks like your `whitethoab` input (but only that one) is probably named `basket[whitethoab][]` or similar, making it a multidim entry.

Comment: yes that's why I mentioned that I double checked and it isn't...strange. I will write it and store it again...

Comment: oops just refreshed couple of times in a row...it is working now. Thanks mate and this is the answer am marking for all the help :D

Comment: No worries, seems odd it didn't work straight away but as long as it works eventually it's all good. FYI I often put `header("Expires: <date in past>"); header('Cache-Control: nocache; must-revalidate');` at the top of my scripts which developing to make sure I always have the current version.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but i think you want this

```
foreach ($itemsBasket as $key => $value) 
{
    if($value > 0){
        echo $key. "<br>\n"
        echo $value . "<br>\n";
    }
}
```